# Redirect to page depending on user input

Tags: html, css, paypal

On the website (http://bread.org.nz/teams) users pick the team they want to donate to (using paypal). How can I redirect to a webpage, depending on who they donate to, so I can give options like "share on facebook that I voted for team 'x' "?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `item_number` but I think that's being deprecated. Now, you can include `custom` variable in your donation link and when it posts back to you (callback), that `custom` variable will be included in the data.

Your donation LINK may look something like this
`...&item_name=RALLY+TEAM+DONATION&custom=I+PICK+TEAM+1&currency_code=NZD`

If this doesn't work, then I think you should achieve it with a custom made solution which of course isn't much reliable.

So, your donation links on the buttons may look like this `example.com/donate.php?team1`. From there, you can get information of **Team 1**, set a PHP session say `$_SESSION['team_chosen'] = 'team1'`.

Now, on the callback page, you can check team in the session and decide further.